# what will be the time complexity of the following program for fibonacci series? code uses dynamic programming

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, dynamic-programming

I know that if I do not use dynamic programming the complexity will be O(2 ^ n) according to the master method for recurrence relation.
`T(n) = T(n-1) + T(n-2)`. But if I use dynamic programming then will it still be O( 2 ^ n)?

```
int [ ] fib = new fib [ 32 ] ;


int fibonacci ( int n) {

      if ( n == 1 ) return 1 ;

      if ( n == 2 ) return 1 ;

      // already calculated fibonacci (n)
      if ( fib [ n ] != 0) return fib [ n ] ;

      return fib [ n ] = fibonacci ( n−1 ) + fibonacci ( n − 2 ) ;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already said by dreamzor, the complexity will be `O(n)` because if you call fibonacci with a value already computed you stop the recursion. He is 100% right.

But, more interestingly the number of calls to the function `fib` is actually `2*n - 3` for `n > 1`. Experimentally, it is quite easy to verify: you can simply add a global variable `counter` that you increment in the function `fib` and then you print it.

This is because for every `n` not computed yet, you'll do 2 recursive calls (except for n=1 or 2).

Now, a bit off topic but, a slight code refactoring:

```
int fibonacci (int n) {
      if (n == 1 || n == 2) {
          fib[n] = 1;
      } else if (fib[n] == 0) {
          fib[n] = fibonacci(n - 1) + fibonacci (n - 2);
      }

      return fib[n];
}
```

Also, I understand that you are probably writing this function in order to learn but you must know that an iterative form, or a tail recursion would be better.

Answer (score 2):

It will be just `O(n)`, since you are instantly returning a value if it's already calculated. Which means, that every value of `fib(n)` will be calculated just once for every `n` you'll have.